# How do I get a Generic and static reference to a MongoDB collection?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, generics, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I want to write a static `getOne<T>()` class method (i.e. it does not require a class instance or the `new` operator to use it) which is also generic, and which returns MongoDB objects as an `Item` which is either a `Book` or a `Film`. This is my initial idea, but now I don't know how to dynamically use the `'books'` or `'films'` collection name strings in place of `'xxx'`.

```
import * as mongodb from 'mongodb';

const CONNECTION_STRING = 'MY_CONNECTION_STRING';
const BOOK_COLLECTION_NAME = 'books';
const FILM_COLLECTION_NAME = 'films';

interface Item {
  _id: string
}

interface Book extends Item {
  bookName: string,
  description?: string
}

interface Film extends Item {
  filmTitle: string,
  duration?: number
}

function isBook(item: Item): item is Book {
  return 'bookName' in item;
}

async function getOne<T extends Item>(): Promise<T | null> {

  const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING);
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db();

  const collection = db.collection<T>('xxx');
  // Instead of xxx I need to use BOOK_COLLECTION_NAME or FILM_COLLECTION_NAME
  // depending on the actual type of T, how do I do that???
  const item = await collection.findOne({});
  if (item !== null) {
    console.log(item._id);
    if (isBook(item)) {
      // Book type specific implementation
      item.bookName += ' (best book ever)';
    }
  }
  return item as T;
}

async function test() {
  const book: Book | null = await getOne<Book>();
  console.log(book?.bookName);
  const film: Film | null = await getOne<Film>();
  console.log(film?.filmTitle);
}

test();
```

Is this even possible? I realise I could workaround this passing it as an argument with something like `await getOne<Book>('books')`, but I want to prevent that (see the `test()` function for the desired usage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with the exact API you want since the type parameters you pass into a function cannot be accessed by the function at runtime (to infer the table name). You can use another approach where the name of the `interface` is inferred from the collection name so that passing `'books'` returns `Book | null`, passing `'films'` returns `Film | null`, and passing anything else is a compile time error.

```
type Collections = {
  books: Book,
  films: Film,
}

async function getOne<Name extends keyof Collections>(name: Name): Promise<Collections[Name] | null> {
  // fetch the actual value here
  return {} as Collections[Name];
}
  
async function test() {
  const book: Book | null = await getOne('books');
  console.log(book?.bookName);
  const film: Film | null = await getOne('films');
  console.log(film?.filmTitle);
  // Argument of type '"comments"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Collections'.
  await getOne('comments');
}

test();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnID6wAJgFzIDOYUoA5rgL666iSyIoBCA9jwNbIIAD0ggSlNJhz5kAIz78AcnAwQK1WiDoAaWSQiUEtAA5hgPEAH4NNekxZto8JMgBiwADZYRYiVIgsPAIYLwwAFWAwT3UqO209AhIAVyg4c0sbZBBkjDloB1wwAE8TFABhHk8YhAyQSQBeGQIFAUoKXgFE5FDvdvcwvWZcOEpikAQe5Im65DoIMAB5EAgAHhU1IVEIcUl%20CGKeGGRK6ohai3qAPgAKEFVYjYgASgoABSgeDGBKNdOauqUADaTwAusgAD7ZZLVK7NZAAegRPQWCAAFsgwGiUIgwMk4J5kAA3AnJFDYqAQWSUvFQEA4RjIUYnKoAy7AsEAbgcBBGYwmUxml0xhjAN2e8IQlmo8kUHUUkOh1WQTTgAHc4FE5gtlhAbgByVr8Sj657cghS%20pVCAAOk8PDoNyNVhtRqeZtklplvQwFA83kVOWVqo1WvmSxWBp9Jo9Ful1rtDpuPpdPsi0Re5qZobA2ojev1UowanAMe5w0g1HFnKAA)

Comment: That workaround was genius, thanks!